# Docker port bindings

Tags: docker, docker-network

`docker ps` command gives me:

```
PORTS
127.0.0.1:40000->8888/tcp
```

Does it mean that port `40000` is busy and nobody can use given port?
I guess that is the case.

If so, why command `lsof -i :40000` gives me an empty output?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that does mean that port 40000 on 127.0.0.1 is being forwarded to a docker container. It does not necessarily mean that the container application is listening on port 8888 on all container interfaces (0.0.0.0) which is needed to complete that connection.

Three reasons that I can think of where `lsof -i :40000` would give no output:

1. You didn't run the lsof command as root
2. Something has killed the docker-proxy process used to relay this traffic
3. You ran the lsof command on a different machine than your docker host. Docker is a client/server app, and by setting `$DOCKER_HOST` you can connect to a remote machine to see the status of a remote host.